# Search and replace regular expressions

Tags: regular-expression

I have a .txt file which is a collection of numbers.
It looks like this:

```
[...]
6 2
7 999
8 105
9 78
10 45
11 6666
[...]
```

up to a 4-digit index.

Now I want to import the numbers as a list in python.
That means I need a list which is

```
[2, 999, 105, 78, ...]
```

So I would like to get rid of the indices, the space after it and set a comma after every entry.
I am not familiar with these, but I know it should work with a regular expression.
Can you help?

Comment: Are the `:` part of the file? Do all lines have two numbers? Should you ignore lines that don't have two numbers? Or if the second number is bigger than 4 digits?

Comment: And where is the "replace" part?

Comment: @aviro No, the colons just mean that the file continues. It start with index 1 and ends with 4570.
All lines have two numbers: The Index and the number that I want to.

Comment: So you don't actually need regular expression. You can just take the second column from all the lines and form them in the way you requested, right? And you're looking for a Linux shell command, not a python code?

Comment: Python is off-topic here. This should be migrated to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks like you can parse this with tools for parsing CSV, e.g. `pandas.read_csv()`.

Comment: @Joooeey The question is not about how to program in Python, but how to parse a file using regex, which using *nix tools would be on topic here.

Comment: Then the question is unclear. It could be read either way. It looks a lot like an XY-Problem. However, as long as it's unclear it's better off closed than migrated.

Comment: @Joooeey Agreed that the question could be clearer, at least in regard of asking how to use *nix tools to do the task, but it doesn't seem to me unclear enough to deserve to be closed. And the participation of users here (including a moderator) points to that it is kind of a consensus.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity To be fair, I left my comment (now deleted) before I understood that this appears to (possibly) be a Python programming question. I agree with Joooeey that the question should have made more sense over at SO, but I will not migrate it there as it is currently not in a good enough state for that. The formulation of the question makes it somewhat ambiguous whether they simply want to output an array in the given format or whether they want to actually use it as an array in Python.

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed, IMO the question is now in a limbo that can only be left if OP makes the necessary clarifications. They didn't say *"I want to do this with Python"* and neither *"I want to do this with *nix"*, and I see no hint in the Q that supports unambiguously one or the other (a tag would be enough!), so let's hope they come back and explain better.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity To that effect, I have closed the question as unclear. It will be reopened when the above mentioned issues are resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Python` as requested:

```
file_path = 'file.txt'

with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    c2 = [int(line.split()[1]) for line in file]

print(c2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Since all of your lines include two numbers, there's no need to use regular expressions. You can just use `awk` command.

One liner:

```
awk 'NR==2 {SEP=", "} {RES=RES SEP $2} END {printf "[%s]\n", RES}' file.txt
```

Multi line for better readability:

```
awk '
  NR == 2 { SEP=", " } 
  { RES = RES SEP $2 } 
  END { printf "[%s]\n", RES }
' file.txt
```

Result:

```
[2, 999, 105, 78, 45, 6666]
```

Comment: Ah duh, of course! I would upvote, but I already had :)

Comment: `NR==2 {SEP=", "} {RES=RES SEP $2}` = `{RES=RES SEP $2; SEP=", "}`. Don't use all upper case variable names though so that a) you can't clash with built-in variable names of which there are far more than most people realise and they vary between awk versions, and b) so your code doesn't look like you're using built-in variables when you aren't and so it obfuscates your code.

Comment: @EdMorton I usually uppercase variables in `awk` to differentiate "local" variables (used in only one scope) and "global". For instace, I use `RES` in every line, and also at the `END` section. But I accept your input.

Comment: Understood. FWIW usually if it's a long script (and so benefits from a convention) then I start the variable with upper case, `NumChars`, if it's required to keep it's value across the whole execution (i.e. some globals), lower `numChars`, otherwise (i.e. the other globals and all locals). I don't find differentiating all globals from locals useful in awk other than declaring function-local variables as such by including them at the end of the function arg list so I can write `function foo(    i) {i=10} ...{for (i=1;i<=5;i++) foo()}` without the global `i` clashing with the local `i`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your input is a key-value two-column text file with no header, you can use the transpose function of datamash to convert the second column to a comma-separated row:

```
$ cat infile 
6 2
7 999
8 105
9 78
10 45
11 6666

$ awk '{print $2}' infile | datamash transpose -t, 
2,999,105,78,45,6666
```

Putting the output between square brackets is trivial. For example, pipe the result to this command:

```
$ sed 's/^/[/ ; s/$/]/'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **Perl**

```perl
~$ perl -ane 'push @a, $F[1]; END { print "[", join(", ", @a), "]\n" };'  file
[2, 999, 105, 78, 45, 6666]
```

Above, Perl is used in `-ane` linewise, autosplit, non-autoprint mode. No `BEGIN` block is necessary. The `@a` array auto-vivicates and elements can be `push`ed onto it--in this case, the `$F[1]` second column after splitting on whitespace. (FYI, `push @a, split /\s+/, $F[1]` works as well, but the `split /\s+/` is superfluous here). In the `END` block, the `@a` array elements are `join`ed as requested, and `print` is called with opening and closing square-brackets.

---

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'my @a.push: .split(/\s+/).[1]; END @a.join(", ") andthen put "[$_]";'   file
[2, 999, 105, 78, 45, 6666]
```

Above, Raku is used in `-ne` linewise non-autoprint mode (fewer command-line flags in Raku as compared to Perl). No `BEGIN` block is necessary, however the `@a` array must be called with `my` (or `our`) to set scope. The input line `$_` is split on `\s+` whitespace (`.split` is short for `$_.split`), and `[1]` the second column is `push`ed onto `@a`. In the `END` block no parens are required: the `@a` array elements are `join`ed as requested, `andthen` reloads the `$_` topic, in order to simplify the final output call to `"[$_]"` with opening and closing square-brackets (`put` adds newline at the end).

---

Sample Input:

```
6 2
7 999
8 105
9 78
10 45
11 6666
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk` to print the second field, and then a simple `sed` replacement to add a `[` at the beginning and replace the trailing `,`  with a `]\n`:

```
$ awk '{ printf "%s, ",$2}' file | sed 's/^/[/; s/, $/]\n/'
[2, 999, 105, 78, 45, 6666]
```

Note that this assumes that everything in the file is an index and its value. No headers, nothing that isn't desired in the output. If that is not the case, please update your question with an input example that includes these.

Comment: You rarely need a pipe to/from sed when you're using awk. If you ever think you do then you should take another look at your awk script :-). The only time I've found it useful would be if I had `STRING`-separated input but didn't have GNU awk so couldn't use a multi-char RS and it was convenient to do `sed 's/STRING/X/g' file | awk -v RS='X' '...'` but even then you don't NEED sed.

Comment: @EdMorton yes, I know you feel that way (you might have made that point once or twice already ;) ). Nevertheless, there are many things I find easier in sed and many I find easier in awk so I will often mix and match in whatever way makes the most sense for what I am trying to do.

Comment: This may well be my ignorance, but if forced to do this in awk, I would have gone for something like `awk '{ k = k ? k", "$2 : $2 } END{ sub($NF, /,/,""); printf "[%s]\n",k}' file` and I find that both harder to parse, and harder to think up than just passing to `sed` for substitutions. Unless writing for a production system with very limited capacity, the tiny little change in efficiency that not starting a second process would bring pales before the extra weight of storing everything in memory anyway.

Comment: That version would fail if `$2` had the value `0` (or `""` which may be valid in other contexts) so I wouldn't do that. It's also always worse to add something then remove it than to not add it in the first place. FWIW I'd write `awk '{ k = k s $2; s=", " } END{ printf "[%s]\n", k }'` or `awk '{ k = (NR>1 ? k s : "") $2} END{ printf "[%s]\n", k }'` or `awk 'BEGIN{ s="[" } { printf "%s%s", s, $2; s=", " } END{ print "]" }` or similar.

Comment: Sorry if I'm repeating myself, I'll try not to make that comment on your answers going forward. It's hard to bite my tongue though! :-). FWIW you could write `awk '{ k=k $2 ", "} END{$0=k; sub(/^/,"["); sub(/, $/,"]"); print}' file` if it's the subsitutions-at-the-end syntax you find clearer.

Comment: Small nit-pick on your original code though - `awk '{ printf "%s, ",$2}' file` is outputting something that isn't a valid text file per POSIX (no terminating newline) so YMMV with what any text-processing tool such as `sed` then does with it but it'll probably be OK in this context where it's piped to `sed` as I think most, if not all, modern `sed`s handle that as you'd like. Other tools not so much (e.g. try piping the awk output to `wc -l` or a shell `while read var; do echo "$var"; done`).

Comment: No worries, @EdMorton. I have been known to make very similar comments myself! Mostly for the `grep foo file | awk` antipattern. I don't mind, I just don't think it's always worth wrangling one tool only for little jobs like this.